# ADODB object ignoring text in excel

Tags: sql, excel, vba, adodb

I have a data table in excel with both numbers and text in the store number column. I need to use sql through an ADODB object in VBA to get a list of the store numbers in the column. I'm using the following to set up the ADODB.

The problem: If the query hits a number first then the field is treated as numbers and texts are ignored. and if a text is hit first the numbers are ignored.

I'm using the following to set up the ADODB. These are in the worksheet module hints `me.`.

```
Public Function Query(qry As String) As ADODB.Recordset
Dim cn As ADODB.Connection '* Connection String
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset '* Record Set
Dim sQuery As String '* Query String
Dim FileName As String

On Error GoTo QryErr

Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
FileName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & ThisWorkbook.Name
cn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & FileName & _
    ";Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;Persist Security Info=False"
cn.ConnectionTimeout = 40
cn.Open

Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
Select Case LCase(qry)
    Case "dry": sQuery = SQLDry
    Case "frz": sQuery = SQLFrz
    Case "fsh": sQuery = SQLFsh
    Case "temp": sQuery = SQLTemp
    Case Else: GoTo QryErr
End Select
rs.ActiveConnection = cn
rs.Source = sQuery
rs.Open

Set Query = rs
If Not rs Is Nothing Then Set rs = Nothing
If Not cn Is Nothing Then Set cn = Nothing

QryErr:
If Err <> 0 Then
Debug.Assert Err = 0
MsgBox Err.Description
End If

End Function
```

And I have the following for the SQL portion.

```
Private Function SQLTemp() As String
Dim Name As String
Name = Me.Name
SQLTemp = "SELECT str([" & Name & "$].Store) as Store " & _
"FROM [" & Name & "$] " & _
"GROUP BY [" & Name & "$].Store"
End Function
```

As you can see I've tryed converting the field to str() but it doesn't help.

How can I get the query to treat the column as text so that all values are returned. I'd like to avoid putting ' in front of all my numbers.

Comment: Excuse me to ask, why do you want to do this using adodb?

Comment: I need this to happen within excel. Is something other than adodb that I can try? I'll try adding IMEX=1, pnuts.

Comment: I got IMEX=1 to work but it doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: Schema.ini : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms709353(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Asked 5 years ago! I had the same problem. The solution for me was to change the data type of the offending columns (those with "special characters" and "TEXT" datatype) to "VARCHAR", or you can remove in the query the special characters, or change the CharacterSet by means of Schema.ini, as @Tim Williams suggests ([msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms709353(v=vs.85).aspx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms709353(v=vs.85).aspx)).